# extract letters from character string

Tags: r, string

I have a vector of strings that have a mixture of letters numbers and other symbols (*, _, -, etc.). There is no discernable pattern in these strings, but I solely want to extract the letters. The following lines help me remove the numbers, but is there a way to modify this to simply extract letters?

```
x <- c("17UA-47", "15Y--51_*")
gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", x)
[1] "UA-"   "Y--_*"

# something like 
gsub("[A-Z]", "", x)
```

EDIT: to clarify, I'm trying to extract the letters, not the numbers from these strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

If you want to extract letters, you can try

```
> gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", x)
[1] "UA" "Y"
```

---

I guess you can use `"\\D"` if you want to keep digits only

```
> gsub("\\D", "", x)
[1] "1747" "1551"
```

or

```
> strsplit(x, split = "\\D+")
[[1]]
[1] "17" "47"

[[2]]
[1] "15" "51"
```

Comment: this would work if I wanted the numbers, but what I'm looking for is extracting the letters.

Comment: If you want to extract letters, you can use `gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", x)` @tnt

Answer (score 3):

You can invert a character class by putting a carat (^) at the beginning:

```
> x <- c("17UA-47", "15Y--51_*")
> gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", x)
[1] "1747" "1551"
```

So now this says match anything that is not a digit and replace it with nothing.  The result is still a string, so if you want a number you will need to run `as.numeric` on the result.

**Edit**

To keep the letters instead of the numbers use `[:alpha:]`:

```
> gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", x)
[1] "UA" "Y"
```

The `strapply` function in the `gsubfn` package allows for more general extraction by extracting what matches instead of removing what you do not want:

```
> x[3] <- "AB-CD12ef"
> library(gsubfn)
> strapply(x, "[[:alpha:]]+")
[[1]]
[1] "UA"

[[2]]
[1] "Y"

[[3]]
[1] "AB" "CD" "ef"
```

Comment: Even simpler `gsub("\\D", "", x)`

Comment: @Greg Snow, this would work if I wanted the numbers, but what I'm looking for is extracting the letters.

Comment: @JilberUrbina, this would work if I wanted the numbers, but what I'm looking for is extracting the letters.

Comment: @tnt,  To keep the letters you can change `[:digit:]` to `[:alpha:]` or `[:upper:]` or `[:lower:]` if you only want upper or lower case letters.  This will remove all non letters (alphabetic characters).  Another option for extracting the match is the `strapply` function in the `gsubfn` package.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the first numbers, then

```r
readr::parse_number(x)
# [1] 17 15
```

If you need all numbers, then

```r
stringr::str_extract_all(x, "[0-9]+")
# [[1]]
# [1] "17" "47"
# [[2]]
# [1] "15" "51"
```

Both can easily be converted to `numeric` with `as.numeric` (either directly for the first, or in `lapply` in the second).

If you need base R, then

```r
regmatches(x, gregexpr("[0-9]+", x))
# [[1]]
# [1] "17" "47"
# [[2]]
# [1] "15" "51"
```

---

... and it appears that ThomasIsCoding's is fastest with a small dataset:

```r
bench::mark(
  readr = readr::parse_number(xbig),
  stringr = stringr::str_extract_all(x, "[0-9]+"),
  base_r = regmatches(x, gregexpr("[0-9]+", x)),
  thomasiscoding = strsplit(x, split = "\\D+"),
  check = FALSE
)
# # A tibble: 4 × 13
#   expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory time                gc                   
#   <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <list>              <list>               
# 1 readr          160.32µs 169.48µs     5888.        NA     2.00  2942     1    499.7ms <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [2,943]>  <tibble [2,943 × 3]> 
# 2 stringr         11.97µs  13.53µs    71411.        NA     0    10000     0      140ms <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [10,000]> <tibble [10,000 × 3]>
# 3 base_r          18.49µs  20.98µs    46515.        NA    18.6   9996     4    214.9ms <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [10,000]> <tibble [10,000 × 3]>
# 4 thomasiscoding   3.95µs   4.12µs   239545.        NA     0    10000     0     41.7ms <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [10,000]> <tibble [10,000 × 3]>
```

If we had much larger data then it looks a little different:

```r
xbig <- rep(x, 1e5)
bench::mark(..., min_iterations = 20) # same as above but using xbig
# Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
# # A tibble: 4 × 13
#   expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory time            gc               
#   <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <list>          <list>           
# 1 readr            14.6ms  15.51ms    59.3          NA    11.9     30     6   506.04ms <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [30]> <tibble [30 × 3]>
# 2 stringr          53.8ms  54.56ms    17.9          NA     1.79    20     2      1.11s <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [20]> <tibble [20 × 3]>
# 3 base_r             1.3s    1.41s     0.714        NA    25.6     20   718     28.01s <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [20]> <tibble [20 × 3]>
# 4 thomasiscoding     77ms  78.09ms    12.5          NA     1.87    20     3       1.6s <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [20]> <tibble [20 × 3]>
```

where base R is surprisingly bad here, and `stringr` is the dominant (by *a little*) method. (Recall that the `readr` method shown as the fastest here only extracts the first number found.)

Comment: cool comparison, but I'm trying to extract the letters, not numbers.